Power pages Authentication
We are building a power pages site and as part of it we need to have the authencated users alone to access the site.
If we use Azure AD for login, it is always taking the user of registration first and then allowing the user to access the site even the user is already in the tenant. Is this expected behaviour? And the Azure AD login is mainly designed for same organization user login is that correct ?
If we use Azure AD B2C also the behaviour is same, additionally it is allowing external domains as well for registration and login.
I am not sure, what i am doung wrong for allowing same organization users without registration.
Then the 2nd one is, i have 2 types of users and the pages to show to the users. I already have AD group and I am not able to restrict the pages based on AD groups. Ex - Admin view, User view.
Redict to home page after the successful login also not happening with Azure AD
Kindly, direct me to the path.

Generally, Power apps is MS Office product, so it use the Azure AD authentication, like SharePoint/OneDrive/Teams . Means in your organization, if some one is authenticated by MS Office, then he can able to login the power app. And incase you think you want to allow an external domain then you have to add an entry in Azure directory for him.
And again If you want to implement one more authentication or a custom authentication (like Gmail) then you have to design a login page/canvas with at least two input fields userid and password.
So, now all user will have to get through these two authentications. And set this custom login page as beginning page of your app.
The moment user click login, then check his user-id availability in SharePoint or other DB.
Second thing is, you want to apply authorization (like admin/sales/hr etc). So  after authentication of an user, you need to get that user's access eligibility from a table (let's say roles). Then using if/else you need to take him to respective page.
Now Create a roles table and create a user management page, allow this user management page to Admin only. As an admin he will pick a list of available user and assign the roles.
